# select2 not working vuejs 3 how can solve this issue

Tags: vuejs3, jquery-select2

select 2 not working vue 3 project backend use `laravel` with `vite`.

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.4.1",
        "jquery": "^3.7.1",
        "vue": "^3.2.36",
        "vue-router": "^4.2.5",
        "vue3-select2-component": "^0.1.7",
        "vue3-toastify": "^0.1.14",
        "vuex": "^4.0.2"
    }
```

when use Select2 componetn after that i get this error
Select2.vue:87 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).find(...).select2 is not a function

when use Select2 componetn after that i get this error:

```
Select2.vue:87 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).find(...).select2 is not a function
```

I search online, and try many solution but still can't solve.

Comment: you need to provide code... specifically [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can produce the error so others can understand what you're trying.  In general, jQuery with Vue is awful idea and if at all possible should be avoided or migrated away from.